# Are T568A/T568B Cables Compatible with USOC Cables?

Tags: ethernet, cables, cat5

[image]

Is it a good idea to use a USOC cable in the same network as a T568A/T568B cable?

I can't seem to find anything about this on the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not a good idea, because as you can see, the pairs are arranged differently. As standard devices expect the pairs to be like they are on T568 wiring, don't expect them to work with USOC wiring as signals that are expected to be kept as a twisted pair is not kept as a twisted pair.

USOC uses RJ61 wiring. Ethernet needs T568 wiring. Both use same connector.